# Why does get-request in React app not return anything from custom Express API

Tags: reactjs, express, server, get, mern

I am creating a MERN web application.

I set up a node.js server which gets data from a MongoDB database and serves it through an Express API. I have it hosted on cyclic.sh. When I access it with my browser, I receive this response which is what I expect:

`[{"_id":"6436561b7adc14205dd193ce","title":"Sons Of Anarchy","body":"Body text goes here...","__v":0},{"_id":"6436561b7adc14205dd193cf","title":"Games of Thrones","body":"Body text goes here...","__v":0}]`

The code for index.js:

```
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Book = require("./models/books");

const app = express()
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);
    console.log(`MongoDB Connected: ${conn.connection.host}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

//Routes go here
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send({ title: 'Books' });
})

app.get('/books', async (req,res)=> {

  const book = await Book.find();

  if (book) {
    res.json(book)
  } else {
    res.send("Something went wrong.");
  }
  
});

app.get('/add-note', async (req,res) => {
  try {
    await Book.insertMany([
      {
        title: "Sons Of Anarchy",
        body: "Body text goes here...",
      },
      {
        title: "Games of Thrones",
        body: "Body text goes here...",
      }
    ]);
    res.json({"Data":"Added"})
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("err", + error);
  }
})

//Connect to the database before listening
connectDB().then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log("listening for requests");
    })
})
```

The code for models/books.js:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const BookSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  body: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', BookSchema);
```

I also set up a React frontend on netlify and I'm trying to access the Express API with this code I'm repurposing from an example I found:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");
  
  const fetchQuestion = () => {
    setQuestion("");
    
    axios
      .get('https://[expressApiUrlCyclic]/books')
      .then((response) => {
        let returnQuestion = response;
        setQuestion(returnQuestion);
                          }
      )
  
  }
            
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchQuestion();
  }, []);
  
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h1>{JSON.stringify(question)}</h1>
      </header>

      <p>text</p>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I get no response from my custom Express API.

If I change the url to 'https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=1&type=multiple' it receives a response and shows me the content.

Why does the request to my custom API on cyclic fail?

Tried adding method and mode to the get-request line. I read CORS makes problems and 'no-cors' solves it somehow.:
`fetch('https://[expressApiUrlCyclic]/books', { method: 'GET', mode: 'no-cors' })`

No change. It doesn't receive anything from my custom Express API.

Comment: You should declare the `app.use(express.json())` middleware in express. Is `[expressApiUrlCyclic]` a fake string or the actual value you are using for the URL?

Comment: ok, where would I write the line "app.use(express.json())"?
[expressApiUrlCyclic] I inserted for this post. In my code it's the actual url.